# Estimate gas in ETH from an approve contract

Tags: ethereum, truffle, hardhat

I woudlike to estimateGas after an approve contract :

```
WETH = weth.address;
USDC = usdc.address;

await usdc.approve(addr1, addr2).estimateGas;
```

When I try this I have this error :

```
TypeError: usdt.approve(...).estimateGas is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle uses different syntax. You need to pass the function params to the `estimateGas()`, not to the `approve()` function.

```
await usdc.approve.estimateGas(addr1, addr2);
```

Docs: http://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#special-methods-on-truffle-contract-objects

*Note: Your code defines `usdc` and then the error message states `usdt`. I'm assuming that's just a typo while creating the question, unrelated to the original issue.*